# How to select the row with same value in between two data frames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, analytics

I have the following huge dataset with me, containing a number of different app names and Sentiments under the attribute sent:

```
                              App      Sent
0            10 Best Foods for You  Positive
1            10 Best Foods for You  Positive
2            10 Best Foods for You       NaN
3            10 Best Foods for You  Positive
4            10 Best Foods for You  Positive
5            10 Best Foods for You  Positive
6            10 Best Foods for You  Positive
7            10 Best Foods for You       NaN
8            10 Best Foods for You   Neutral
9            10 Best Foods for You   Neutral
10           10 Best Foods for You  Positive
11           10 Best Foods for You  Positive
12           10 Best Foods for You  Positive
13           10 Best Foods for You  Positive
                           ...       ...
64289  Houzz Interior Design Ideas       NaN
64290  Houzz Interior Design Ideas       NaN
64291  Houzz Interior Design Ideas       NaN
64292  Houzz Interior Design Ideas       NaN
64293  Houzz Interior Design Ideas       NaN
64294  Houzz Interior Design Ideas       NaN`
```

I want to figure out the app which has generated approximately the same ratio for positive and negative sentiments (i.e finding the apps which have the same number of positive and negative sentiments or closest number one)
I tried separating the above data frame into two data frames with values positive and negative.
And then grouping then with count
For example:
Positive dataframe p:

```
                                                    Sent
App                                                     
10 Best Foods for You                                162
104 找工作 - 找工作 找打工 找兼職 履歷健檢 履歷診療室                      31
11st                                                  23
1800 Contacts - Lens Store                            64
1LINE – One Line with One Touch                       27
2018Emoji Keyboard  Emoticons Lite -sticker&gif      25
21-Day Meditation Experience                          68
2Date Dating App, Love and matching                   26
2GIS: directory & navigator                           23
2RedBeans                                             31
2ndLine - Second Phone Number                         17
30 Day Fitness Challenge - Workout at Home            27
365Scores - Live Scores                                5
3D Live Neon Weed Launcher                             2
4 in a Row                                            17
7 Day Food Journal Challenge                           9
7 Minute Workout                                      10
7 Weeks - Habit & Goal Tracker                        10
8 Ball Pool                                          104
850 Sports News Digest                                38
8fit Workouts & Meal Planner                         137
95Live -SG#1 Live Streaming App                       34
A Call From Santa Claus!                              20
A Word A Day                                           3
A&E - Watch Full Episodes of TV Shows                 30
A+ Gallery - Photos & Videos                          24
                                                 ...
HipChat - Chat Built for Teams                        19
Hipmunk Hotels & Flights                              30
Hitwe - meet people and chat                           2
Hole19: Golf GPS App, Rangefinder & Scorecard         18
Home Decor Showpiece Art making: Medium Difficulty    16
Home Scouting® MLS Mobile                             13
Home Security Camera WardenCam - reuse old phones     18
Home Street – Home Design Game                        42
Home Workout - No Equipment                           24
Home Workout for Men - Bodybuilding                   22
Home workouts - fat burning, abs, legs, arms,chest     8
HomeWork                                               1
Homes.com  For Sale, Rent                            11
Homescapes                                            27
Homesnap Real Estate & Rentals                        25
Homestyler Interior Design & Decorating Ideas         19
Homework Planner                                      33
Honkai Impact 3rd                                     54
Hopper - Watch & Book Flights                         54
Horoscopes – Daily Zodiac Horoscope and Astrology     21
Horses Live Wallpaper                                 22
Hostelworld: Hostels & Cheap Hotels Travel App        42
Hot Wheels: Race Off                                  14
HotelTonight: Book amazing deals at great hotels      93
Hotels Combined - Cheap deals                         15
Hotels.com: Book Hotel Rooms & Find Vacation Deals    39
Hotspot Shield Free VPN Proxy & Wi-Fi Security        17
Hotstar                                               14
Hotwire Hotel & Car Rental App                        16
Housing-Real Estate & Property                         8

[853 rows x 1 columns]
```

And the negative dataframe n:

```
                                                    Sent
App                                                     
10 Best Foods for You                                 10
104 找工作 - 找工作 找打工 找兼職 履歷健檢 履歷診療室                       1
11st                                                   7
1800 Contacts - Lens Store                             6
1LINE – One Line with One Touch                        8
2018Emoji Keyboard  Emoticons Lite -sticker&gif       1
21-Day Meditation Experience                          10
2Date Dating App, Love and matching                    7
2GIS: directory & navigator                            6
2RedBeans                                              2
2ndLine - Second Phone Number                          7
30 Day Fitness Challenge - Workout at Home             2
4 in a Row                                             3
7 Minute Workout                                       1
7 Weeks - Habit & Goal Tracker                         4
8 Ball Pool                                          106
850 Sports News Digest                                 1
8fit Workouts & Meal Planner                          19
95Live -SG#1 Live Streaming App                       20
A Call From Santa Claus!                              14
A&E - Watch Full Episodes of TV Shows                  3
A+ Gallery - Photos & Videos                           7
A+ Mobile                                              9
ABC Kids - Tracing & Phonics                           1
ABC News - US & World News                            29
ABC Preschool Free                                     8
                                                 ...
Hill Climb Racing                                     13
Hill Climb Racing 2                                   11
Hily: Dating, Chat, Match, Meet & Hook up             29
Hinge: Dating & Relationships                         11
HipChat - Chat Built for Teams                        26
Hipmunk Hotels & Flights                               1
Hitwe - meet people and chat                           7
Home Decor Showpiece Art making: Medium Difficulty     5
Home Scouting® MLS Mobile                             12
Home Security Camera WardenCam - reuse old phones      4
Home Street – Home Design Game                        13
Home Workout - No Equipment                            1
Homes.com  For Sale, Rent                             3
Homescapes                                            25
Homesnap Real Estate & Rentals                         6
Homestyler Interior Design & Decorating Ideas          7
Homework Planner                                       4
Honkai Impact 3rd                                     22
Hopper - Watch & Book Flights                         18
Horoscopes – Daily Zodiac Horoscope and Astrology      1
Horses Live Wallpaper                                  2
Hostelworld: Hostels & Cheap Hotels Travel App        12
Hot Wheels: Race Off                                   6
HotelTonight: Book amazing deals at great hotels      17
Hotels Combined - Cheap deals                          7
Hotels.com: Book Hotel Rooms & Find Vacation Deals    21
Hotspot Shield Free VPN Proxy & Wi-Fi Security         3
Hotstar                                               14
Hotwire Hotel & Car Rental App                         6
Housing-Real Estate & Property                        10

[782 rows x 1 columns]
```

Doing this I could find the app name which has equal p["Sent"].values:

```
df=p.loc[p["Sent"]==n["Sent"]]
print(df)

Output:
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing dataframes with different rows.

I would do like this. Consider this situation.

```
name    p   n
app1    5   5
app2    8   6
app3    7   7
app4    10  8
app5    3   NaN
```

This code print the name of app and num where 'p' and 'n' numbers are the same.

```
# make dataframe p, n
p = pd.DataFrame([5, 8, 7, 10 ,3], index=['app1', 'app2', 'app3', 'app4', 'app5'], columns=['p'])
n = pd.DataFrame([5, 6, 7, 8, None], index=['app1', 'app2', 'app3', 'app4', 'app5'], columns=['n'])

# combine p and n with concat
df = pd.concat([p, n], axis=1)

# check equality
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.iloc[i]['p'] == df.iloc[i]['n']:
        print(df.index[i], df.iloc[i]['p'])

# Outputs are
# app1 5.0
# app3 7.0
```

Comment: Great this works! Thanks a lot. But does this concat method give a sorted list because im getting a warning in the console: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned. A future version
of pandas will change to not sort by default.

To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=False'.

To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass 'sort=True'.

Comment: The Warning means that concat sort rows with names. My pandas(0. 24.2) doesn't  show waring so I didn't noticed, sorry. Please try pd.concat([p, n], axis=1, sort=False) or True. Search "pandas concat sort warning", or read https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Comment: Yeah I used sort=False